# transform $.get to node.js request

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, get, request

i'm using geolocation, i was handling everything on client side, now I wat to handle this from

Currently using it as;

```
var url = "youtube.com",
    options = { 
        key: API_KEY,
        video: "vid_id"
    };


$.get(url, options, function(data) {
    console.log(data)
})
```

I want to use it with nodeJS HTTPS, so i tried;

```
var https = require("https"),
    url = "youtube.com",
    options = { 
        key: API_KEY,
        video: "vid_id"
    };


https.get(url, options, function(data) {
    console.log(data)
})
```

but i cant get it work I hope someone can convert this.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `request` module for node.js. Install it by running:
`npm install request`.

```
var request = require('request');

request(`youtube.com/?key=${key}&video=${video_id}`, function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
  console.log('body:', body); // Print body of the response.
});
```

Comment: NB: No need to use `--save` with npm5

Comment: In this simple use-case, direct string handling a la `${key}` is fine; however, for more complex use-cases (e.g. a routable SPA) consider templating, e.g. https://github.com/bramstein/url-template

Comment: Yes, I would recommend that you use the `qs` option to automatically build the query string in more complex cases.